# starting activity on imageview click in custom array adapter

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have made a custom adapter class

here is the code

```
public class CustomArrayAdapterForReceipts extends ArrayAdapter<Receipt> {
    private final Activity context;
    public final ArrayList<Receipt> receipt;

    public CustomArrayAdapterForReceipts(Activity context, ArrayList<Receipt> receipt) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout_receipts_listview, receipt);
        this.context = context;
        this.receipt = receipt;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView referenceNo;
        protected TextView comments;
        protected ImageView receiptImage;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View view = null;
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_receipts_listview, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.referenceNo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowReceiptTitle);
            viewHolder.comments = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowReceiptComments);
            viewHolder.receiptImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowReceiptImage);

            Receipt file =  receipt.get(position);
            final byte[] blob = file.getImage();
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob);
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 30, 30, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            viewHolder.receiptImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

            viewHolder.receiptImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), TransferController.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("image", blob);
                startActivity(myIntent);
             }
        });

            viewHolder.referenceNo.setText(file.getReferenceNo());
            viewHolder.comments.setText(file.getComments());


            view.setTag(viewHolder);

        return view;
    }       
}
```

The problem exists at

```
myIntent.putExtra("image", blob);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

`startActivity` is not being recognized... Please tell me, i want to start a new activity here. What should i do...

BEST Regards

Comment: do context.startActivity

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try like this you can get

```
v.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```